# PHP read, stored php var in text file

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to stored php values in a string/file.
I have a text file with "var1=foo&var2=foo2" etc in it, is there a way to read the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to open the file and [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the contents into an associative array.

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');

parse_str($file, $params);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/db9Tsibs).

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can change it, theres always `serialize()` and `unserialize()`